# PHP unlink file using AJAX doesn´t return result to javascript after unlink files

Tags: php, ajax

I have problem to get the result after unlink files using ajax php.
The unlink function does the job completely, but can not return the result to javascript.

in **JAVASCRIPT****

I use very normal ajax with POST method

in **PHP**

```
$params=$_POST['params'];
$id_edit=$_POST['id_edit'];
```

//Then I get the name of image from database using $_POST['id_edit']; for where clause.

```
$del_img="imgfolder/".$row['name_img'];
```

//then unlink the file

```
if (file_exists($del_img)) {
        unlink($del_img);
    }
```

////After unlink finshed send result to ajax

```
echo"ok";
```

***The files was deleted completely but the ajax can not get the result back.
PS: I have no error and no problem with ajax at all. But just can not make php to give the result back. I guess it because of unlink file can not give the result to ajax ?

Comment: Show your Javascript code and look for any logged error messages from your PHP.  You *are* logging PHP errors, no?

Comment: Hei, Thanks for answer...
I use a very normal javascript and I´m quite used to ajax but this case (unlink file) is something new I ever tried. I got no error just can not get the result. 

And I have tried another test by using this without ajax to see if there´re error, but i have no error at all.

How did I know that I have no error ? yes I have use the document.getelementbyid() method and get the result in a div.
It work fine without unlink method.

I also test it without ajax. i got no error.

Comment: It's questions like these that stand to get lost in confusion and obscurity.

Comment: Hi Fred -ii, I want you to try it.
With a very simple ajax php with unlink() in php.
And see if you get the result back to javascript or not.

I have tried to echo and so on....But once I delete unlink() in php the echo in php could be send back to javascript.

Comment: Is `echo "ok";` enough? Don't you need to set some headers, like maybe `Content-Type:` ?  AJAX can get picky on what constitutes a valid reply.  Post your AJAX code.  What do you see if you visit the web site with Chrome, with the dev tools running, and the network tab up in the bottom half of the screen while you use this page?

Comment: Could you try, on the PHP side, to save some text in a file before/after the unlink. Like this you can ensure that the PHP does not leave in an error mode like an exception because of the unlink

Comment: Hi Paul....Don´t worry, in my ajax I have all you said. The reason I don´t post it here because it´s too  long and as I mention that it´s a simply ajax php which work perfectly with other case but not unlink method in php !

If you don´t mind I want you to test by your self. Creat a simple ajax php and in php you try to unlink file from folder somewhere and try to echo it after...you´l see no matter what you echo, it will not return to javascript !

Comment: koopajah, I don´t think it´s error. Because I have also tried t use this script/ document without ajax to test if there´s an error. But I got no error and the file was unlink successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to fix when you don't show your JavaScript code, but this worked for me!

```
function send(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 0 || xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
            xmlHttp.open("POST", example.php, true);
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerRespons;
            xmlHttp.send("what ever you want to send");
            }else{
          setTimeout('send()', 1000);      
        }
   }


function handleServerRespons(){
```

If you want to use response text (this do not work with IF statements):

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4){
    if (xmlHttp.status === 200){
        if(url === 'sections/verify.php'){
            var text1Response = xmlHttp.responseText;
```

If you want to use xml:

```
        var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            var xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
             message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
             if (message = "ok"){
               alert("ok");
            }else{
               alert("fail");
          }
      }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replying. I want you to try with unlink file and see if you get the result back. I have no problrm with javascript at all. I use it with many functions without any problems. But unlink file-->I can not get the result.

Comment: Ok, I see. I've got no experianse with unlink file, so there i cant help you :/ do you want me to delite the post?

Comment: Nono, you´re very kind !

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the Error after all.
I user json to return the error as array.
that´s why I can not get the error msg.

But it´s strange...I test with pure php(no ajax) why didn´t i get the error msg ?

**BTW**

The error was fixed by putting. ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."img_folder/".$row['name_img']);

Because in the beginning I had just  $del_img="imgfolder/".$row['name_img'];

That´s why I got meesage if file does not exist.

AFTER THAT I FOUND
Because of the $row[img] is empty.
And the unlink functiom did nt know name
of images to delete.